# Automount SMB share when NAS becomes available

Tags: macos, nas, smb, automount

I have a NAS server at home which shares content through SMB. The NAS server isn't always on, only really use it when I need to, so I use WOL (WAKE ON LAN) etc...

Is it possible to automatically mount the SMB shares once the NAS server is awake? Something to check if the server is up, and then automatically mount the shares?

I'm using OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do better: you can mount the remote resources only when needed. This is done by means of  *automount*, a program that comes with your OS.

Suppose you have a NAS server called MyNAS, with a share called MyMusic, and you want to instruct automount to mount the share only if you are trying to access it. Then add this line

```
  /MyMusicMountPoint          auto_resources
```

to the file /etc/auto_master; here /MyMusicMountPoint is whatever mount point you choose for the remote resource MyMusic. Then create a file called /etc/auto_resources with the following line:

```
 MyMusic -fstp=smbfs ://MyNAS/MyMusic
```

Now, when you start *automount* by means of the simple command *automount*, you will find the SMB share in /MyMusicMountPoint/MyMusic.

Comment: What is "-fstp"?  According to the docs, shouldn't that be -fstype=smb?  Additionally, why is there a : before the url?  The man page shows 'smb  -fstype=smb //guest@smbserver/share' as an example

Comment: @EricB. Nope, not necessarily: see http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/01/24/using-the-mac-os-x-automounter.html for instance, or here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4927134

Comment: Is there a way to use a password from the keychain instead of specifying it in the auto_xxx config file?  I've created a separate question for it here: http://superuser.com/q/812582/130030